# Electron window.innerHeight and vh units reporting incorrectly except in full screen

Tags: javascript, css, electron

**The problem:**

I'm noticing that the `vh` units and `window.innerHeight` calculation in my Electron BrowserView are both coming out 28px larger than the actual viewport window height. I would do a workaround like `calc(100vh - 28px)`, except the numbers actually come out correctly when I enter full screen on the window, and I don't know how to account for that exception. Is this an electron bug or am I configuring something wrong?

**Some context:**

I don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm constructing the browserview bounds with an offset of 42 like so:

```
const view = await new BrowserView({
    webPreferences: {
      backgroundColor: '#FFF',
      nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
      contextIsolation: !process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  win.setBrowserView(view);

  let bounds = win.getBounds();
  view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 42, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height - 42 });
```

The Y is offset to make space for a nav bar, which is stored behind the view in the main window.

Comment: Do you have a horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yes, it's only visible in full screen for some reason